# Shouldn't a restricted PodSecurityPolicy use 'MayRunAs' instead of 'MustRunAs'

Tags: kubernetes, podsecuritypolicy

The k8s documentation has an example for a restricted PodSecurityPolicy:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#example-policies

containing the following snippet:

```
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
```

I am wondering why they use the rule 'MustRunAs' instead of 'MayRunAs'.

The documentation states for 'MustRunAs': "Uses the minimum value of the first range as the default."

Therefore my understanding is that both the supplementalGroup and the fsGroup will be defaulted to 1 for any container (if not specified otherwise in the pod or container securityContext) whereas if 'MayRunAs' had been used no default supplementalGroup / fsGroup would have been assigned.

Therefore would it not have been better to use 'MayRunAs' instead of 'MustRunAs' for a restrictive PodSecurityPolicy?

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore would it not have been better to use 'MayRunAs' instead of 'MustRunAs' for a restrictive PodSecurityPolicy?

In my point of view `MustRunAs` is more restrictive than `MayRunAs`. Let's see the [Pull Request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/65135/commits/a577b50012bc9df2212f83678bca2c3b11c759d6) where `MayRunAs` was introduced:

> Adds "MayRunAs" value among other group strategies. This strategy
> allows to define a certain range of GIDs for FSGroupStrategy and
> SupplementalGroupStrategy in a PSP.
>
> This new strategy works similarly to the "MustRunAs" one, except that
> when no GID is specified in a pod/container security context then no
> GID is generated for the respective containers.

And here is the Realease Notes:

> PodSecurityPolicy objects now support a `MayRunAs` rule for `fsGroup` and `supplementalGroups` options. This allows specifying ranges of allowed GIDs for pods/containers without forcing a default GID the way `MustRunAs` does. This means that a container to which such a policy applies to won't use any fsGroup/supplementalGroup GID if not explicitly specified, yet a specified GID must still fall in the GID range according to the policy.

For both cases when GID isn't specified in the container's definition:

- for `MustRunAs` will be set default (minimal)
- for `MayRunAs` will not be set default.

Comment: That is exactly the premise of my question. Why would it be better to set a default supplemental group and a default fsgroup? How would this be more restrictive? It just adds more groups to the user which are probably not needed and therefore opens unneccessary doors making it more unsecure.